# BuddyPress admin bar links are broken

Tags: plugins, buddypress, admin-bar

I have activated [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/) on a blog but the link `My Account` on the admin bar is broken. I have configured BuddyPress to auto create pages but still the problem persists. I have been searching Google for two days now. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Define _broken_. Is the markup invalid? The URLs? Javascript errors? Something else … ?

Comment: it just redirects to the 404 error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddypress requires pretty permalinks to function properly. If you have set them up already try to go to the permalinks admin page and resave them and see if that helps.

If your host won't let wordpress write to an .htaccess file, that page will also show you what should be in it.

http://codex.buddypress.org/troubleshooting/navigation-links-return-404-errors/

http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/before-installing/

Comment: .htaccess doesn't work. when i set permalink to date, month and post or any url pattern other then by page id or post id (example.com/?postid=324). it doesn't work. But it works fine with example.com/?postid=324

Comment: using this(example.com/?postid=324) kind of url pattern buddy press links don't work. but wordpress pages work fine.

Comment: Buddypress **requires** pretty permalinks to function properly! If you can't use them then that is a different problem and buddypress isn't broken because of it... What do you mean by _.htaccess doesn't work_ ?

Comment: By that I mean, what is wrong with the actual file? Can you find it (some servers hide it) Can Wordpress write to it? What is in it? etc.